# Finding mean, autocorrelation, and power spectrum of $y[n]=(x∗h)[n]$ where $x[n]$ is zero mean white gaussian noise

Tags: power-spectral-density, autocorrelation, gaussian

If given $x[n]$ is zero mean white Gaussian noise with variance $\sigma_x^2$, and a filter with a known impulse response $h[n]$, how would I find the mean, autocorrelation, and power spectrum of $y[n] = (x*h)[n]$?

I believe $\mu_y = \mu_x = 0$. I'm not sure how to find the other 2 components. I don't want to give actual values for $h[n]$ because I'm looking for an explanation, not just an answer.

Comment: Correct, that is what I meant.

Comment: This is discrete-time, yes?  "$n$" is an integer index, not a continuous-time value like $t$?

Comment: This is pretty much standard statistical communications stuff.  There are answers in the right textbooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $h(t)$ is the impulse response of a linear system,
there are many ways to get to the desired result.

1. Here's one for the Power Spectrum:

   By definition, the power spectrum $S_{y}(\omega)$ of a WSS signal $y(t)$ with
   Fourier Transform $Y(\omega)$ is

   \begin{align} S_{y}(\omega) = \mathbb{E}\bigg[Y(\omega)\overline{Y(\omega)}\bigg] &=
   \mathbb{E}\bigg[HX\overline{HX}\bigg]\\
   &=\mathbb{E}\bigg[H\overline{H}X\overline{X}\bigg]\\
   &=\mathbb{E}\bigg[H\overline{H}\bigg]\mathbb{E}\bigg[X\overline{X}\bigg]\\
   &= S_h(\omega)S_x(\omega)\\
   &= |H(\omega)|^2\sigma^2 \end{align} where $x(t)$ is zero-mean white noise
   with variance $\sigma^2$, and using the fact that $\mathbb{E}[AB] =
   \mathbb{E}[A]\mathbb{E}[B]$ for $A,B$ independent.
2. The autocorrelation is the inverse transform of the Power Spectrum so
   \begin{align}
   R_y(\tau) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}S_y(\omega)e^{j\omega t}d\omega\\
   &=\sigma^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}S_h(\omega)e^{j\omega t}d\omega\\
   &=\sigma^2R_h(\tau)
   \end{align}

---

Of course, you can go further if you know $h(t)$, i.e. $R_h(\tau)$ and $|H(\omega)|^2$:

For example if $h(t)$ is the impulse response of a Low Pass Filter with bandwidth $B/2$, you'd get $$R_y(\tau) = \sigma^2 B\, \text{sinc}\bigg(\frac{B\tau}{2}\bigg)$$

Comment: I did this for continuous time, but too lazy to change now to discrete. The derivation is pretty much the same, anyways. Robert, please edit if there's anything wrong or not up to your standards of correctness!

Comment: Well, $(t)$ becomes $[n]$ and $\infty$ becomes $\pi$ in the integrals.  Some parenths become brackets to indicate discrete arguments.